# SBT: Access generated classes in Build.scala

Tags: scala, build, sbt, sbt-buildinfo

I am facing an issue with SBT managed sources.

I want to import some automatically generated classes (like BuildInfo.scala) from `src_managed` to my Build.scala SBT file.

Although all classes will be generated successfully, I can not import them in Build.scala (class not found).

All my build classes are located in `project` folder.

How can I configure my build in order to get access to generated classes from SBT build file?

**EDIT**

My `BuildInfo.scala` is located in `{root}/project/src_managed/sbt-buildinfo/`. What I am trying to do is to import this class in a `Build.scala` class located in `{root}/project/`. But I get a compile error: `project/Build.scala:8: object BuildInfo is not a member of package *******`

Comment: It sounds like those files are actually part of your build definition, in which case they should be in `project/src_managed`, not your root `src_managed`?

Comment: @SethTisue you are right, I've changed the src_managed dir, but I still get the compile error (please see my edit).

Comment: Hmm... if I switch to my build definition project with `reload plugins` then type `show sourceManaged` I see `/Users/tisue/tmp/project/target/scala-2.10/sbt-0.13/src_managed`, so it looks like that's where it expects the sources to be?